# Regex into Oracle expression - (\b|\d)(?i)INT(\b|\d)

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a regex expression as such:

`(\b|\d)(?i)INT(\b|\d)`

It works as I'd like on https://regex101.com/

But when trying to make it work with Oracle's Regex... I started with this:

`SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('INT', '(\b|\d)(?i)INT(\b|\d)') AS FOUND FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1 ;`

and various variations, but not having success, was hoping to get some help

Note the first parameter 'INT' would of course be a field in a table that I wanted to search in, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you plan to just check for a match**, you can "decompose" `\b` into `(^|\W|\d)` / `($|\W|\d)` and use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('INT', '(^|\W|\d)INT($|\W|\d)', 1, 1, 0, 'i')
```

Here, `(^|\W|\d)INT($|\W|\d)` matches

- `(^|\W|\d)` - start of string, or a non-word char, or a digit
- `INT` - an `INT` string
- `($|\W|\d)` - end of string, or a non-word char, or a digit.

The sixth argument to [`REGEXP_INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm) is the *match parameter* argument, `'i'` means case insensitive.  So, this function will return the position of the first character of the first occurrence (see the fourth *occurrence* argument) of the match (see the fifth *return_option* argument), that is searched from the first char in the string (see the third *position* argument)

To return the exact position of `INT` using this single regex approach is not possible, since `\W` will consume a non-word char at the start.

Comment: This is not quite the same as `\b` has zero-width and if `\W` is matched instead then you will find the index of the character before the start of the match.

Comment: @MT0 The point here is to check if there is a match. This will suffice.